# How to do division in 2's complement

Tags: binary, numbers, system, twos-complement

Compute the following binary arithmetic operations using the 2’s complement method. Show all the steps clearly.

(a) Division of -40 by -4

I want to know the method of how to do division between two 2s complement numbers. please somebody explain??

Comment: See https://www.cuemath.com/numbers/binary-division/ or https://byjus.com/maths/binary-division/ and https://paulmason.me/blog/2018-05-19-dividing-binary-numbers-part-2/